# Heroku Deployment SassError: File to import not found or unreadable. Works fine locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, sass

Attempting to deploy to heroku for the first time, and i've been getting this sasserror which causes the build to fail and reject.

Steps taken for resolution

1. Delete node sass and node modules / reinstall / push to master repo
2. Adjust import path to @import './scss/_variables.scss';
3. Delete the first import to check if that file was the issue
4. Update node to support node-sass compatibility

Question

1. Create React App has webpack built internally, do i need to add my own webpack config for sass-loaders, css-loaders, style-loaders?

- i've only ever used webpack with rails before, if i do need webpack, for my output params, what should replace the "bundle.js" i get from rails?

Terminal response

```
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.24.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.12
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        > nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/node_modules/nodemon
remote:        > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
remote:        
remote:        Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
remote:         > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
remote:        
remote:        added 358 packages in 10.306s
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_f7e8f26d
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > node-sass@6.0.0 install /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        > node scripts/install.js
remote:        
remote:        Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v6.0.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node
remote:        Download complete
remote:        Binary saved to /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
remote:        Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.gWg6N/node-sass/6.0.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node
remote:        
remote:        > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > core-js@3.12.1 postinstall /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/core-js
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > core-js-pure@3.12.1 postinstall /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/ejs
remote:        > node ./postinstall.js
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > node-sass@6.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        > node scripts/build.js
remote:        
remote:        Binary found at /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
remote:        Testing binary
remote:        Binary is fine
remote:        added 2124 packages from 812 contributors and audited 2131 packages in 43.95s
remote:        
remote:        139 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 81 vulnerabilities (80 moderate, 1 high)
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:        
remote:        > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_f7e8f26d/client
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        ./src/App.scss
remote:        SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: ./scss/_variables.scss.
remote:                on line 2 of src/App.scss
remote:        >> @import './scss/_variables.scss';
remote:        
remote:           ^
remote:        
remote:        
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.gWg6N/_logs/2021-05-25T08_12_53_624Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.gWg6N/_logs/2021-05-25T08_12_53_642Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

App.scss

```
// Abstracts
@import 'scss/variables';
@import 'scss/mixins';

// Base
@import 'scss/globals';

// Components
@import 'scss/header';
@import 'scss/showcase';
@import 'scss/hero';
@import 'scss/feature';
@import 'scss/postLanding';
@import 'scss/footer';
@import 'scss/auth';
@import 'scss/postList';
...etc
```

client package json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "secure": false,
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

server package json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "jounii",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\" ",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "Andrew Huang",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.771.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "node-geocoder": "^3.27.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  }
}
```

File tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpWnm.jpg)

Comment: Is it compiles locally if you execute `npm run build` ?

Comment: @YuriyGyerts yes i just ran ```npm run build``` and it compiled fine

Comment: So the problem only reproduces on heroku and only when it contains `@import 'scss/variables';`

Comment: to my knowledge, yes, it only reproduces on heroku. I've tried to delete ```@import 'scss/variables';``` but it was the same for the next import as well. should i delete my heroku repo and rebuild/repush?

Comment: Could you please share general file structure of your app to understand where you store scss and where you are trying to get it. By the way on Angular we have special config where we specify additional paths where to find scss if it was not found.

Comment: client/src/index.js is my entry file
client/src/App.js is being passed to index.js

client/src/App.scss is where my main scss file is located

client/src/scss/all other scss files

Comment: Yelling "PLEASE HELP" is not cool. Explain your problem. Be patient.

Comment: @tadman thanks tadman - first time asking a question on stackoverflow, thats great advice

Comment: try to add `src/assets` folder, move whole scss files inside, then try to use in App.scss like @import src/assets/scss/...

Comment: @YuriyGyerts smh.. that did the trick the build succeeded!
- im getting an Application error now while checking my domain but ill go figure out whats wrong. lol. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: The biggest thank you - a 'like' in front of accepted answer )) Have a nice evening )) by my time zone ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

f you set `SASS_PATH=node_modules:src`, this will allow you to do imports like

```
@import 'styles/colors'; // assuming a styles directory under src/, where _colors.scss partial file exists.
@import 'nprogress/nprogress'; // importing a css file from the nprogress node module
```

Comment: i have a .env file in my root dir, which contains the sasspath as well!

Comment: accept answer located in comments on the main thread